# multiple raising verb in a sentence

Tags: syntax

how would the deep structure looks like for a sentence that has multiple raising verb like 'Tom happens to be believed to have wanted to like linguistics' ?

Answer (score 1):

[[someone believe [Tom Past want [Tom like linguistics]]] happen]